# How to download a Signed Google Storage URL on client machine

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have this code that creates a signed URL to download a specific file in my bucket:

```
exports.download = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const userID = req.query.userID;
  const downloadID = req.query.downloadID;
  const fileName = req.query.fileName;

  admin
    .storage()
    .bucket()
    .file(`userUploads/${userID}/${downloadID}/${fileName}`)
    .getSignedUrl({
      version: "v4",
      action: "read",
      expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    })
    .then((signedURLArray) => {
      const url = signedURLArray[0];
      // return res.download(url);
      return res.redirect(url);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.send(err);
    });
});
```

I've tried:

```
res.setHeader(
    `"content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${fileName}"`
  );
```

with `res.redirect` but it just gives me a `HTTP_TOKEN_ERROR` . If I use `res.redirect()` without setting any extra headers, it will just view the file on the browser, not download it - I only want the user to be able to download the file.

Obviously, `res.download` does not work as the file in question is not on the server, it is served on some other server where my bucket files are located (most likely some `storage.googleapis.com` domain)

UPDATE:

As you can see by the response request:

[image]

It's sending the right data back to the browser

Comment: Let's try `res.header('Content-disposition', "attachment; filename=" + fileName);`

Comment: @hoangdv it just views the file again it doesn't download it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you redirect to google's server, it becomes responsible for the headers of the response, and specifically for the `Content-disposition` one. Metadata of the files stored in google storage can be set up on or after the file is uploaded.
Your header should look like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.ext..."
```

Please check these docs to see possible options on how to set the metadata for the files manually via gsutil:

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-disposition

#### UPDATE

In order to generate signed URL with custom header (e.g. `Content-Disposition`) with the Google storage admin API it should be added via a config parameter `responseDisposition` with desired value

Usage example:

```
...
admin
    .storage()
    .bucket()
    .file(`userUploads/${userID}/${downloadID}/${fileName}`)
    .getSignedUrl({
      responseDisposition: "attachment",
      version: "v4",
      action: "read",
      expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    })
...
```

See MDN reference for possible header values here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

See documentation for nodejs api library for google storage [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage) and link to the lines where file attachment properties, `promptSaveAs` and `responseDisposition` are explained [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/be259280d8707e49d1037b5b81e4470f52464a57/src/file.ts#L2897).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as you can see by the bottom half of my question, I have already tried that.

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: From mdn doc: ```The first parameter in the HTTP context is either inline (default value, indicating it can be displayed inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or attachment (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if present).``` so, `attachment` part is important, and in your case `inline` is sent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: How do I stop it from sending ‘inline’ then? As I send the exact same header as you

Comment: Add responseDisposition property when you call get signedUrl, set it accordingly. Check jsdoc in this file around lines 2897-2902 https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/main/src/file.ts

Comment: Thank you, If you add all of those comments into your answer to make it more comprehensive then I shall award the 50 bounty

Comment: Thank you Nathan, added required steps into the answer. Good luck!